# Is a combination of credit card's number and expiration date unique?

Tags: php, mysql, credit-card

I'm building a small database driven application to store the multitude of **my own** credit, debit etc. cards.

Let's assume that the number of cards I have is much higher than it really is.

What I'm slightly concerned about is the extent to which a card can be uniquely identified - from what I gathered the number itself could be reused by the issuer.

My proposed ID consists of the whole card number, year & month (3 separate columns) - would that be enough - are credit card's number and expiration date unique? Are years better off stored as YY or YYYY?

There's no need to adhere to any rules (such as PCI DSS) given the app runs solely on a separate, internetless localhost, only my data is supposed to be stored there and no transactions are to take place.

Comment: I will use the YYYYMM format (not the YY) plus the credit card number. This key will be unique.

Comment: Obviously, the expiration date MM/YY is not unique on its own. When considered in relation with card number, the combination should be unique. Regarding storing the expiry year format: I'd go with YY and save yourself some conversions, I have never seen card with YYYY format on it.

Comment: @AD7six One of the cases when the card number would be reused (recycled would be more fitting here) is after the expiration of the other card(s). The data in the DB may be 50+ years old (expired cards), so duplicates would be much more likely).

Comment: Going with just `YY` is what caused things to break after 1999, because people wanted to save the space of the two characters required for a full year.  Use the full year, not just the last two.

Comment: @AD7six so we can assume that the issuer would never make 2 cards with the same number and expiration date, right? Meaning, the whole card number plus year & month will be enough to ensure uniqueness even for someone as paranoid as myself? I know about the odds, especially given the scope (just my cards), but that's just how I program.

Comment: Most credit card processors expect the expiration date as a two-digit year (usually as `MMYY`). In practical terms, it's unambiguous: credit cards typically expire within a few years of issue, so there's only one meaningful interpretation for any two-digit year.

Comment: even though card numbers may be re-issued - you will never be reissued the same card number (it will be re-issued to someone else) - as this is only your cards you can just use your card number for identification.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Even if the card number only once per person bit is true then how would this apply to anonymous, single use, prepaid cards?

Comment: @duskwuff Mostly true, but I swear I read in the question (as well as his comment) that he's storing expired cards as well, and that is when it would start to matter - in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The card number alone is sufficient to uniquely identify a credit card account — it identifies the issuer and account that the card is tied to, so it must necessarily be unique. It is possible for the expiration date to be *updated* on a card (which will also give it a new CVV2, for what it's worth), but it's still considered the same card when this happens. Indeed, some credit card processors will allow merchants to automatically "update" cards in their system which have expired, by sending back the new expiration date when the old date has passed.

If your goal is simply to track the pieces of plastic in your wallet, though, tracking them by the card number and expiration date will be sufficient. The card number is already unique, as I already mentioned, and the other bits of information on it are only updated along with the expiration date.

Comment: Some citations would be nice, what you said is only partially true, whether you realize that or not is a different matter.

Comment: @user3137630: If you believe there's something inaccurate in my answer, please **tell me what it is**. Don't just hint that you know something that I don't.